# Does Apple have a way to dispatch a block to a queue only if it's different from the current queue?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios7

My method uses variables meant to be accessed only from a custom queue. Sometimes I call my method from that queue and sometimes from the main queue.

When the method is called from the custom queue I want to run all of its code synchronously so there's no dispatch overhead. But when it's called from the main queue I want to dispatch to the correct queue.

I'm curious if Cocoa provides a built-in way to do this. I currently explicitly check for the correct queue like this:

```
static const char * CustomDispatchQueueKey = "com.example.custom";

- (instancetype)init
{
    ...
    _queue = dispatch_queue_create(CustomDispatchQueueKey, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_queue_set_specific(_queue, CustomDispatchQueueKey, (void *)CustomDispatchQueueKey, NULL);
    dispatch_set_target_queue(_queue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));
    ...
}

- (void)customTask
{
    BOOL onCustomQueue = dispatch_get_specific(CustomDispatchQueueKey) == CustomDispatchQueueKey;
    void (^block)() = ^{
        // access data that needs to be accessed from the custom queue
    };
    if (onCustomQueue) {
        block();
    } else {
        dispatch_async(_queue, block);
    }
}
```

Does Apple have a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`dispatch_get_current_queue()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW9) against [`dispatch_get_main_queue()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW11)

```
if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // Main queue
} else if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == _queue) {
    // Your custom queue
} else {
    // Another queue
}
```

You can also use [`+[NSThread isMainThread]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/isMainThread) if you like too.

Comment: This check doesn't work. It is actually documented that this check doesn't work. Use only `[NSThread isMainThread]`.

Comment: To be precise the docs state that: `When called from outside of the context of a submitted block, this function returns the main queue if the call is executed from the main thread. If the call is made from any other thread, this function returns the default concurrent queue.` So it *does* work - **within a block**..